about javascript 'open.window' return value diff
on firefox or chrome.
open the console


let arr = []

arr.push(window.open('https://google.com'))
arr.push(window.open('https://twitter.com'))



arr[0].close()
don't work
arr[1].close()
is work
can someone explain the principle behind it?
how can I achieve these two effects if I am a website maintainer?
is there any way to make arr[0].close() effective?
Thanks!

Are you sure the Google window is opening? I think Google has restrictions on how its pages can be opened.

Are there errors in the console?

it shouldn't open either without user-interaction.  (that's to avoid annoying popups...)  But even then I believe most browsers limit you to a single popup per user-action.  Can you describe more about what you are trying to do?

Both pages can be opened
no error in the console
just open the chrome , open a blank tag , open console , and input those code

swap the order, what do you observe? don't include google, use some other site ... what do you observe? based on these observations, what do you conclude?

I want to understand how Google does this and then add it to my website

fair enough, your question didn't mention that you made the connection with google, rather your question implies that it's to do with the ordinal position in the array

I think what you want is "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy

see, you say, in the question "is there any way to make arr[0].close() effective?" - but in a comment you say you want arr[0].close() to NOT close the tab, making it INeffective - the opposite of what you state in the question

@browsermator yeah, I just configured this on nginx, and now my website cannot be closed using close() either. Thank you very much

You can only open one window at the same time. if you want open more, the broswer will prevent and has attention in the address bar at first time. You can get more window object if you agree with it.

